# memcpy returning incorrect results

Tags: c++, audio

This test example I've made works as expected:

```
FLAC__int32 array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
FLAC__int32 const *const handle(array);

FLAC__int32 temp[10];
std::vector<FLAC__int32> base;

base.resize(10);
memcpy(&base[0], handle, 10 * sizeof(FLAC__int32));

for (size_t i(0); i < 10; i++)
    cout << endl << "[ " << i << " ] " << base[i];
```

However, with the code below, I can't get the `memcpy` to work correctly. How do I correct this so that `memcpy` makes correct copies of the buffer?

`Note: _buffer contains binary data which was decoder by libFLAC.`

```
FLAC__StreamDecoderWriteStatus
Source::write_callback
    (FLAC__Frame const* _frame, FLAC__int32 const *const _buffer[])
{

    cout << endl << "Head index [ " << index_ << " ].";

    memcpy(&data_[index_], &_buffer[0], _frame->header.blocksize * 
        sizeof(FLAC__int32));

    index_ += _frame->header.blocksize;
    cout << endl << "Tail index [ " << index_ << " ].";


    for(size_t i(0); i < 400; i++) {

        cout << endl << "Buff [ " << i << " ] " << _buffer[i];
        cout << endl << "Data [ " << i << " ] " << data_[i];

    } // jump

    return FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_WRITE_STATUS_CONTINUE;
} // main
```

And below is how I resize the vector and reset the index:

```
void
Source::metadata_callback (const ::FLAC__StreamMetadata *metadata)
{

    ...

    total_samples_ = metadata->data.stream_info.total_samples;

    ...

    data_.resize(total_samples_); index_ = 0;

} // main
```

Comment: Since you're copying to `data[index_]` shouldn't the loop below be taking that into account rather than starting with index 0?

Comment: @Retired Ninja The loop below is just to see the first 400 values of the copied data. The `std::vector<FLAC__int32> data_;` gets resized to 20750 in this example.

Comment: I suspect `&_buffer[0]` is the problem. `_buffer` is an array of pointers. It's unclear if those pointers just refer to contiguous pieces of memory or if they're disjointed.

Comment: @greatwolf The API for libFLAC dose not say, but only shows: http://xiph.org/flac/api/classFLAC_1_1Decoder_1_1Stream.html#FLAC_1_1Decoder_1_1Streamb5

Comment: Are you trying to do a shallow copy (copying the pointers) or a deep copy (copying the things the pointers point to)?

Comment: @Beta I need to do deep copy, because i need the binnery data which contains the decoded audio.

Comment: How do you know how many pointers are in the array? I don't see a size parameter for it -- do we assume the last element is null terminated?

Comment: @greatwolf I am not sure myself if the last element is null terminated, i would assume so. But I am not all that accustomed with libFLAC myself yet either. I need to see if I can find the information within the libFLAC documentation.

Comment: @greatwolf I do know however, is that _frame->header.blocksize is updated with the new size for the buffer every time i get callback. So _frame->header.blocksize would tell me the range within the buffer...

Comment: What is the type of `data_`? Is it `FLAC__int32[]` or `FLAC__int32*[]`?

Comment: @Beta Type is std::vector<FLAC__int32> data_; but now i am tring with FLAC__int32* data_; so data_ = new FLAC__int32[total_samples_]; thus i am attempting to *_buffer[i] >> data_[index_]; Thx...

Comment: By the way, some output from _buffer (cout << endl << "Buff [ " << i << " ] " << _buffer[i];) are as following:Buff [ 40 ] 0x200001000
Buff [ 41 ] 0x100000001000
Buff [ 42 ] 0x1000
Buff [ 43 ] 0x100000001
Buff [ 44 ] 0
Buff [ 45 ] 0x22
Buff [ 46 ] 0x100000001000
Buff [ 47 ] 0x1986000000e2
Buff [ 48 ] 0x20000ac44
Buff [ 49 ] 0x10
Buff [ 50 ] 0x510e
Buff [ 51 ] 0xb123fe34019e300d
Buff [ 52 ] 0x6953e324f8d14780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a deep copy (that is, you want to copy the `FLAC__int32` values, not the pointers to them), and you don't seem to care whether you construct a container of those values or of pointers to those values. So `memcpy` is the wrong tool. Let's start with a very simple case:

```
void foo(int * buf)
{
  int data = *buf;
}
```

Then try copying an array to a vector:

```
void foo(int * buf[])
{
  vector<int> data(10);

  for(unsigned int k=0; k<3; ++k)
    data[k] = *buf[k];
}
```

Then the full solution:

```
FLAC__StreamDecoderWriteStatus Source::write_callback(FLAC__Frame const* _frame, FLAC__int32 const *const _buffer[])
{
  cout << endl << "Head index [ " << index_ << " ].";

  data_.resize(_frame->header.blocksize);
  for(size_t k=0; k<_frame->header.blocksize; ++k)
  {
    data_[index_+k] = *_buffer[k];
  }

  index_ += _frame->header.blocksize;
  cout << endl << "Tail index [ " << index_ << " ].";

  for(size_t i(0); i < 400; i++)
  {
    cout << endl << "Buff [ " << i << " ] " << *_buffer[i];
    cout << endl << "Data [ " << i << " ] " << data_[i];
  }

  return FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_WRITE_STATUS_CONTINUE;                                      
}
```